# Batch Scripts - Need to specify to use an ANSI console and execute a command

Tags: ruby, windows-7, batch-file

This is a noob question at its best but Google isn't finding what I need.

I have a ruby script that I need to fire off via task scheduler.  I thought I did it right by using the following:

```
cmd /k ruby test.rb
```

This works when starting the .bat file from the folder.  However, if it runs from taskeng.exe it fails because its looking in my system32 folder.  I don't want it to run from system32 so how do i format this to run from say, c:/dev/

Again, sorry for the extremely noob question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave out `cmd` of that and just use

```
ruby test.rb
```

or rather (in your case):

```
ruby C:\Users\Foo\test.rb
```

or something like that. Giving the complete path to the script usually helps in finding it ;-)

In any case, if you need the working directory you can set it in the scheduled task itself. Something akin to the following:

[image]

Likewise, if you actually need `cmd` in there. Just fill out the *Start in* field and you have a working directory.